# Reading data csv file from folder level above app.R file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a general path to read in my csv for a shiny app. I moved my app.R file in to a folder 'R' and my data folder is in the same level as the R folder so that it looks like this structure:

- myAppFolder:

1. data (includes csv to read into app.R)
2. R (includes app.R)

I have written my path as follows:

```
df <- read_csv("./../data/myData.csv")
```

But I'm getting an error that my csv does not exist in the directory 'R' folder. How can I make it go up one level to access my data folder?

Thank you!

Comment: i have always had the file in the Root R project directory or a child, you could use the [HERE](https://here.r-lib.org/) package in R that helps navigate file paths in R.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your working directory is set as the "R" folder, you can access files from the other folder using just the two `..` before the `/`. The `..` brings you up one folder from the working directory and then you can work you way forward again as specified...

```
df <- read_csv("../data/myData.csv")
```